# How to colorize Minitest output by default?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, minitest

After a recent Ruby upgrade from 2.6 to 2.7, I no longer get colorized Minitest output as I used to in Windows 10. I can still get colorized output with `minitest-reporters` or `minitest-color`, but these do not apply by default—they need a `require` or a command-line argument. It would be nice to have colors by default.

I'm fairly certain this feature came from a gem that I had installed, but due to my careless upgrade I seem to have lost it, and I've had no success finding it again even after hours of searching.

I have installed `win32console`, but that didn't make any difference. I also tried using Ruby 2.6 again, to no avail.